# Upload a file using FS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I get an error when I try to upload a file, it works in local but it doesn't work on my remote server...

My error :

```
    [sbaf.fr.3005-53 (out) 2014-03-05T20:19:59] { [Error: ENOENT, rename '/tmp/1e426309d298d9ab1d099e1017584058']
[sbaf.fr.3005-53 (out) 2014-03-05T20:19:59]   errno: 34,
[sbaf.fr.3005-53 (out) 2014-03-05T20:19:59]   code: 'ENOENT',
[sbaf.fr.3005-53 (out) 2014-03-05T20:19:59]   path: '/tmp/1e426309d298d9ab1d099e1017584058' }
```

My controller :

```
photoDAL.prototype.save = function(photo, file, callback) {
    photo.file = file.name;
    var photo = dbContext.photo.build(photo);

    var file_tmp = file.path;
    var file_name = file.name;
    var file_type = file.type;
    var file = './public/images/photo/'+file_name;

    fs.rename(file_tmp, file, function(err){
        if( err ) console.log(err);
    });

    photo.save().success(function(photo) {
        callback(photo);
    }).error(function(error) {
        callback({message: error});
    });
};
```

**EDIT #1 :**

Screenshots of my ExpressJS app...

Screenshot 1 : http://glui.me/?i=eweyq4ovennej50/2014-03-05_at_20.34_2x.png/
Screenshot 2 : http://glui.me/?i=1n2cjv57jd2fmwq/2014-03-05_at_20.33_2x.png/

**EDIT #2 :**

My code :

```
console.log(process.cwd());
console.log(__dirname);
```

The console :

```
[sbaf.fr.3005-71 (out) 2014-03-05T21:55:48] /home/anthoc/apps
[sbaf.fr.3005-71 (out) 2014-03-05T21:55:48] /home/anthoc/apps/sbaf.fr/app/dal
```

Comment: Does public `./public/images/photo/` folder exists ?

Comment: Yes, see edit #1 above...

Answer (score 0):

So this: `var file = './public/images/photo/'+file_name;` is a relative path based on `process.cwd()`. Presumably if your server process was started with your app repo root as the cwd, all should be well, but probably that is not the case. It's more robust to not rely on the `cwd` but use `__dirname` and construct paths relative to the location of the current javascript file. So give that a try and see if it fixes it. You can confirm one way or another with: `console.log(process.cwd())` in your controller module to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  using `__dirname`. Here is how I would do it:

```
photoDAL.prototype.save = function(photo, file, callback) {
photo.file = file.name;
var photo = dbContext.photo.build(photo);

var file_tmp = file.path;
var file_name = file.name;
var file_type = file.type;
var file = __dirname + '/public/images/photo/'+file_name;

fs.rename(file_tmp, file, function(err){
    if( err ) console.log(err);
});

photo.save().success(function(photo) {
    callback(photo);
}).error(function(error) {
    callback({message: error});
});
```

};

Now, if you're code is in a folder and your target is in the parent, like me:

```
-root
  - public
     -photos
  -server
     -upload.js
```

You can add a function to the string proto.

```
String.prototype.getParent = function () {
        // Be cross-platform
    var replaced = this.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), '/');
    var index = replaced.lastIndexOf('/');
    return replaced.substring(0, index);
};
```

Now call `__dirname.getParent()` as many time as needed (`__dirname.getParent().getParent()...`).

Comment: Ok but is there a solution working in local and also on a remote server?

Comment: I don't really understand. This will work on heroku or nodejitsu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formidable module. easy to use

https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable